# Reading root and then multiple sub-collections in Firestore

Tags: angular, angular5, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have two collections A and B in Firestore and I’m using Angular 5.2 and Angularfire2.
A is the root collection and each document in A holds a sub-collection B.

I have the following challenge:

1. I need to read a subset of from collection A
2. For each of the documents in the subset need to read the underlying sub-collection.
3. Data will then be presented in a table.
   Reading the sub-set will require using .snapshot(), since I need the Id from the sub-set. Then I want to iterate through the result and read each underlying sub-collection.

I’ve tried to use switchMap, concatMap, concatAll, etc, but I get different type an errors for each one of them.

```
const rootCollection = this.afs
  .doc(collection.USERS + `/${email}`)
  .collection<MyMeasurement>(collection.MY_MEASUREMENT, ref =>
    ref.where('selected', '==', true).orderBy('name', 'asc')
  )
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(changes => {
      return changes.map(action => {
        const data = action.payload.doc.data() as MyMeasurement;
        data.id = action.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    })
  );

const concatCollection = rootCollection.pipe(concatMap(data => data.forEach(element => {      
  // her comes the inner observer 
  // Her is the error message:
  // Argument of type '(data: MyMeasurement[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: MyMeasurement[], index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  //Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
})))

const subscribe.concatCollection(data => console.log(data));
```